# Which is the right way to install different packages based on user selection using WIX?

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3.7, wix-extension

We have a big problem. 
We want to create a WIX installer that if the machine where I'm running the installer is a:

1) Windows 7 or higher I have to show an interface where I can collect the user choice about which database I have to use (MS Access, MS LocalDB, MS SQL Server).

2) version before Window 7 I don't have to show the interface for the database selection because I want to force my application using MS Access.

After this step, if the user has selected the MS LocalDB choice I have to install the SQL Server Express LocalDB Runtime. The runtime installer has 2 files, one for x86 and one for x64. So I have to install the runtime ONLY if user want to use LocalDb and install the proper package checking the machine type (x86 or x64).

So we created a bundle with a chain. The chain contains:

1) our application WIX installer

2) the SQL LocalDB runtime for x86

3) the SQL LocalDB runtime for x64

We tried 2 ways:

1) put the selection into an interface placed in the WIX installer: we can show and hide the interface for database selection but we cannot pass the value of the selected database to the bundle to decide if and which runtime install

2) put the radio button into the options page of the bundle package but we cannot hide the options button if my operating system is before Windows 7. We tried the thmutil extension (http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/thmutil/) but it is not possible to insert a contition to disable the button.

So our questions are:

- Which is the right way to install different packages based on user selection?
- Is there a way to allow a bidirecdtional communication between WIX installer and bundle?

Thanks!

Comment: Rob Mensching said "No. There is no way for Packages to communicate Properties back to the Bundle" as you can see here

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Bootstrapper-question-td7593254.html

Is it true?